# reflection with stacktrace / stackframe to get both methods name and parameters

Tags: c#, debugging, reflection, helpermethods

while writing the question subject I came across
some other allmost related post ...leading to MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx

but i couldn't manage to extract the bit of code i needed

i just learnd how to get method name with a helper method based on st and sf as following :

```
    public void setLogView(View ViewMode)
    {
        AAdToAppLog();

        Lview_AH_AutomationLog.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        ColumnHeader ColHeadRowNo = new ColumnHeader();
        ColumnHeader ColHeadFunction = new ColumnHeader();
        ColumnHeader ColHeadContent = new ColumnHeader();
        ColumnHeader ColHeadTime = new ColumnHeader();

        Lview_AH_AutomationLog.View = ViewMode;
        Lview_AH_AutomationLog.Columns.Add(ColHeadRowNo);
        Lview_AH_AutomationLog.Columns.Add(ColHeadFunction);
        Lview_AH_AutomationLog.Columns.Add(ColHeadContent);
        Lview_AH_AutomationLog.Columns.Add(ColHeadTime);
        ColHeadRowNo.Text = "#";
        ColHeadFunction.Text = "Function Name";
        ColHeadContent.Text = "Content";
        ColHeadTime.Text = "Time";
        ColHeadRowNo.Width = 45;
        ColHeadFunction.Width = 150;
        ColHeadContent.Width = 150;
        ColHeadTime.Width = 100;
    }



    public void AAdToAppLog(string FunctionOutPut = "N/A")
    {
        string t = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.ff");
        string h = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");
        ListViewItem FirstCell= new ListViewItem();
        FirstCell.Text =h+":" +pre0Tosingle_9(LogCounter.ToString());//Another helper puts 0 infront <=9 digits
        Lview_AH_AutomationLog.Items.Insert(0, FirstCell);
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(); 
        StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);
        string FunctionName = sf.GetMethod().ToString().Replace("Void", "").Replace("System.Windows.Forms.", ""); 
        FirstCell.SubItems.Add(FunctionName);
        FirstCell.SubItems.Add(FunctionOutPut);
        FirstCell.SubItems.Add(t);

        LogCounter++;

    }
```

so in every method i want i just put the

```
AddToAppLog()
```

that method contains my call to AddToAppLog() and then reports(Via ListView) the name of method and i just added the time of the call.

there's two things i would like to address in this post , about my implementation of that helper metod :
the "FunctionName" i recive from sf.GetMethod is nice that it throws the type of the Parameter of a given Method i liked the idea , only that it is containing parameter.type's Father + Grandfather + Great-Grandfather, but i would like only the bottom Type :

```
System.Windows.Forms.View
```

this is one of the shortest (: and i tried to get to **View** by it self via playing with .Replace()
so is there anothere way to strip it down or actually another method in same family that extract it the way i mentiond above or i could use a list containing every possible most-used types and do a foreach with stringReplace?

and more importently , **how do i get the Method(parameterName) as well ?**

thanks alot in advance !!

can someone Show An easy to comprehend , Simple syntax Example
of getting parameters name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux of this is the line that involves `sf.GetMethod()`; if you instead store that:

```
var method = sf.GetMethod();
string name = method.Name;
var parameters = method.GetParameters();
```

you have access to the full signature, and note that the `.Name` is just the simple name - not the full declaring type-name, etc. You can of course access `method.DeclaringType.Name` if you want more context. Note that you can only get the ***declaration*** of the parameters; you can't get their *values* via any normal mechanism.

However!!! I will also observe that all this has a performance cost associated with reflection and stack-walking. If you have the C# 5 compiler, you may prefer:

```
public void AAdToAppLog([CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
{ ... }
```

which means that the **compiler** will supply the name of the caller *voluntarily* (as a constant geneated in the IL) - no need to either supply it, or go walking the stack to figure it out. You cannot, however, get the parameters like this.

Comment: i undrerstand , i was going-to have a check on C# 5 but i'm still on the tip of the iceberg with c# so no rush(: And as for the performance-costs , i will make a switch so it will act only when needed and not at all time , thanks for the parameter's Name Mr Gravell  !!

Comment: gonna check on Getparameters see what it yields is there a trick to add the parameter type without it's ancestors like in my example with ....Forms.View extraction of View By it self

Comment: parameters.ToString() yields `System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[]` instead of parameters

Comment: @LoneXcoder I never said to call `parameters.ToString()`; that is an array of the parameters - you may iterate it as you choose, getting the `.Name` / `.ParameterType` of each...